# CKEditor: Make Shift+Enter same as Ctrl+Enter

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in a CKEditor, a new line is created. When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens.

How can I make pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, to behave same as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that [*Enterkey*](http://ckeditor.com/addon/enterkey) plugin is loaded. Then use [`editor.setKeystroke()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setKeystroke) to assign a new keystroke to an existing command (<kbd>Enter</kbd> is 13) ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/y4tt3/)):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            this.setKeystroke( [
                [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 13, 'shiftEnter' ]
            ] );                        
        }
    }
} );
```